# Failed to install clarifai for "instapy"

Tags: python, clarifai, instapy

Hey guys I'm trying to use the nstaPy bot written by python

and I tried to install the requirements using **pip** but unfortunately I came across with an error that I'm unable to

handle. the error is with installing "clarifai" library  and I'm Getting These two:
 `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`

and

`error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

**Please Help Me Handle This**

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the wrong python and pip version.

Use    `python3 -m pip` or `pip3 install` to install clarifai.

Let me know.